# Jump to method call from method definition in Intellij [Scala Perspective]

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

We have a shortcut key to jump to method definition from wherever the method is called, i.e. by using Ctrl+leftclick over the method name. But what if I am currently on the method definition and I want to go that location where the method is called or used. Any shortcut for this?

I've tried Ctrl+alt+F7 it did'nt work?

Comment: Consider this scenario, for Example I have a Class with N no of methods how do I navigate between method definition and method call.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ctrl+B is used to find the function define, also could be used to find where the function was called. Ok in my idea 15.0.3.

Answer (score 4):

It is usually the same shortcut, unless, you guys redefined it: ctrl-click on a method use takes you to the definition, ctrl-click on the definition finds usages.